# Firefox select box - remove gray background while keeping the arrow heads

Tags: css, firefox, html-select

I'm having a small problem on styling my select boxes. Every thing seems to be OK when i check for those select boxes from Chrome. but in Firefox it is not neat. what i wanted to do is remove only the gray color background but i wanted to keep the arrow heads same way.

I used

```
select 
{
-moz-appearance: none;
    text-indent: 0.01px;
    text-overflow: '';
}
```

But after that code run the arrow heads of the select boxes has been gone.

Hope there will be a great solution for that.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you will try to remove background color with -moz-appearance, arrow icon will also gone.
Alternative approach is you can add your own arrow icon in select box.

```
@-moz-document url-prefix()
{
    select
    {
        -moz-appearance: none;
        background: url("./../../images/your-icon.svg") no-repeat right center; 
    }
}
```

Replace url with your own icon's path in above code snippet.